# getActivity() vs this.getActivity() in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

I am new in Android, and I'd like to know if there is a difference between `getActivity()` and `this.getActivity()` in Fragment clases.
For exemple we have a method in a siple class(doesn't extend Activity or Fragment) like:

```
 public static void method(Context context){

... some code

    }
```

If we want to use it,  just call it in our fragment class:

```
MyMethodClass.method(getActivity());
```

or

```
MyMethodClass.method(this.getActivity());
```

I know both are working but I need a proffesional opinion.

Thanks.

Comment: Both are the same. When you not define the "this" its automaticly used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are the same. The this keyword refers to the current object.

```
public class Car {
    int speed = 10;

    public void move() {
        //using this.speed or speed makes no difference here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending from `Fragment`, both `getActivity()` and `this.getActivity()` will call [Fragment#getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()), so as others said, it makes no difference. Both will lookup for the method in the parent class.
A small correction: tha sample code that you provided:

```
MyMethodClass.method(getActivity());
```

would work if `method()` was a static method. Otherwise you should call it like this:

```
    MyMethodClass.this.method(getActivity());
```

But that's just basic Java ;)

Comment: thx for remark, I edited the code.
We can use also an instance like: `MyMethodClass myMethodClass = new MyMethodClass();`  and acces method `myMethodClass.method(getActivity());`

Answer (score 0):

Use **getActivity()** keyword instead of 'this' keyword in Fragments